# deleting duplicate files with parenthesis in the name, only if original exists

Tags: python, list, file, duplicates, glob

i didn't really find anything that suits my needs, and i am not sure how to proceed.

i have **lots** of photos, scattered across different folder, while many of them are just duplicates. like for example:

20180514.jpg(1).jpg
20180514.jpg
or
20180514(1).jpg

now, i want to create a python script, which looks for files with a parenthesis, checks if a related file *without* parenthesis exists and deletes the file with the parenthesis. with my lack of python skills, i managed to search for all files with wildcards:

`parenthesisList = glob.glob('**/*(*)*', recursive=True)`

and could theoretically delete them from there, but with 30k+ pictures, i wouldn't dare just deleting them, not knowing if they really had an original file or not.

the tricky part now is to compare that list to another list, which is something like:

`everythingList = glob.glob('**/*(*)*', recursive=True)`

and to evaluate, which of the files in
`parenthesisList` have a file with the same name, except the parenthesis.

bonus point would be to only delete the file, if the size of the file is the same or less, but don't *really* need that. thanks for any help!

EDIT: my post sounds like i want someone to do it for me, but if it wasn't clear, my question is: how do you check if items from list A contain items from list A minus '('?

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import listdir


for filename in listdir(r"C:\Users\...\Pictures"):
    # check if file name contains parenthesis 
    if "(" in filename:
        os.remove(r"C:\Users\...\Pictures\\" + filename)
```

Note that this will also remove folders names with "(".

Comment: i'm not sure, but doesn't your code just check if there is a parenthesis in the name, nd then delete it? it doesn't check if there is another file without the parenthesis, or does it?